# How to assign a tag to an event that would allow for 3d conflict detection on a google calendar?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I'm attempting to create a resource management system that would allow members of my office to reserve a room through forms, creating a calendar event on a public calendar.

The issue I am facing in the creation process revolves around conflict checking complications, due to the fact that I would like to have all the calendar events located on one calendar per office.  The result is multiple resources on one calendar, and the need for my conflict checking script to not only check for conflicting events but also evaluate the room in which the events are.

Ideally, I would need the script to check first if there are any conflicts, and if there are, it would then check the room name of the conflict event.  If the events are in different rooms, it will approve the event creation. If otherwise, it would be denied, and the form respondent would receive an email.  I've scoured through the documentation, but with my limited knowledge of the language and coding in general I haven't been able to find a good solution.

At first, I thought I would be able to compare event descriptions, which I would set as the room name based on input from the form submissions.  When I called all of the conflicts within the start and end time I would then evaluate their descsriptions with the description of the event to be created and check from there.  Unfortunately, from what I tested, it is not possible to do with multiple conflicting events.

I then have what I have listed here where I have an array of the rooms submitted in the past, from the spreadsheet attached to the form, and it checks through them.  The issue here is that it doesn't account for start and end times only room names.

My principal question in all of this would be, is there a way to assign a tag of some sort to my event on creation that I would then be able to call back in the conflict checking portion of my script.  Ideally, this tag would be something I can assign myself and then evaluate with the new form submission data.  I think the best way would be through inviting a room resource to the event, but I have been unable to figure out how to do that as well.

```
function getConflicts(request){
  var conflicts = request.calendar.getEvents(request.dateTime, request.edateTime);
  //var description = conflicts.getDescription(); 
  if(conflicts.length >= 1){
        Logger.log(conflicts.length);

    for (var i=0; i<conflicts.length; i++) {
  if (request.room != request.slroom[i]) {

    request.status = "Approve";
  } else if (request.room == request.slroom[i]) {
    request.status = "Conflict";

  }
}}
else     request.status = "Approve";

}
```

Full Script:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

var calendarb = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("link");

function Submission(){
  var row = lastRow;
  var slrow = (lastRow-1);
  this.timestamp = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
  this.name = sheet.getRange(row , 3).getValue() + ": " + sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
  this.email = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  this.dateTime = sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue();
  this.edateTime = sheet.getRange(row,7).getValue();
  this.room = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
  this.slroom = sheet.getRange(2, 5, (lastRow-1)).getValues();
  this.roomstart =sheet.getRange(2, 6, (lastRow-1)).getValues();
  this.roomend = sheet.getRange(2, 7, (lastRow-1)).getValues();


  //this.roomInt = this.room.replace(/\D+/g, '');
  //this.status;
  this.calendar = calendarb;
  return this;
  var event;
}



function getConflicts(request){
  var conflicts = request.calendar.getEvents(request.dateTime, request.edateTime);
  //var description = conflicts.getDescription(); 
  if(conflicts.length >= 1){
        Logger.log(conflicts.length);


    for (var i=0; i<conflicts.length; i++) {
  if (request.room != request.slroom[i]) {

    request.status = "Approve";
  } else if (request.room == request.slroom[i]) {
    request.status = "Conflict";

  }
}}
else     request.status = "Approve";

}


function draftEmail(request){
  request.buttonLink = "link";
  request.buttonText = "New Request";
  switch (request.status) {
    case "Approve":
      request.subject = "Confirmation: " + request.room + " Reservation for " + request.dateTime + "-" + request.edateTime;
      request.header = "Confirmation";
      request.message = "Your room reservation has been scheduled.";
      break;
    case "Conflict":
      request.subject = "Conflict with " + request.room + " Reservation for " + request.dateTime + "-" + request.edateTime;
      request.header = "Conflict";
      request.message = "There is a scheduling conflict. Please pick another room or time."
      request.buttonText = "Reschedule";
      break;
  }
}

function updateCalendar(request){

  var event = {
    summary: request.name,
    location: 'Location',
    description: request.room,
    start: {
      dateTime: request.dateTime.toISOString()
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: request.edateTime.toISOString()
    },
    attendees: [
      {email: request.email}
    ],
    tag: request.room

  };
  event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, "Calandar ID");
  // request.calendar.addSmsReminder(10);
    Logger.log('Event Tag: ' + event.description);

  Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.id);
   }
  



function sendEmail(request){
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: request.email,
    subject: request.header,
    htmlBody: makeEmail(request)
  })
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, 8).setValue("Sent: " + request.status);
}


function main(){
  var request = new Submission();
  getConflicts(request);
  draftEmail(request);
  if (request.status == "Approve") updateCalendar(request);
  sendEmail(request);
}
```

My spreadsheet is set up in this order

A: Timestamp
B: Email Adress
C: Name
D: Location
E: Room
F: Start Date & Time
G: End Date & Time

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTvJ0mElZbc5T0QIjktJz0EuuYiU0BUsD6KubxxHpaYkVTGWIWcypeASgRCV6YejKw4O87_zNmGRV2P/pubhtml)

Comment: Can you please also provide the function calling `getConflicts` so we could understand more how to replicate your issue?

Comment: I added the full script to the post

Comment: Can you also provide a sample data of your responses? Preferably a sheet published publicly.

Comment: I published a sample sheet and have put the link at the bottom of my post - thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, you store your `room` details in your event's description. Why not use the descriptions of the conflicted events to check if the room is still available? In this manner, we don't need to tag our events.

I also modified some lines as to improve the efficiency of your whole script. Kindly see changes below.

#### Code:

```
function Submission() {
  // get values by bulk
  var rowValues = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 7).getValues().flat();
  // avoid using this as that contains another values you don't need
  // create a request variable instead
  var request = {};
  request.timestamp = rowValues[0];
  request.name = rowValues[2] + ": " + rowValues[4];
  request.email = rowValues[1];
  request.dateTime = rowValues[5];
  request.edateTime = rowValues[6];
  request.room = rowValues[4];
  request.calendar = calendarb;
  // No need to store previous lists of rooms and their time. 
  // See getConflicts for clarification
  return request;
}

function getConflicts(request) {
  var conflicts = request.calendar.getEvents(request.dateTime, request.edateTime);
  // Since you stored the room into the description
  // Filter the conflicts by comparing conflicts' descriptions to the room
  if(conflicts.filter(conflict => conflict.getDescription() == request.room).length > 0)
    request.status = "Conflict";
  else
    request.status = "Approve";
}
```

#### Changes:

- Get the row values by bulk.
- Create `request` variable instead of using `this`. The latter contains other values you don't need.
- Removed getting past room and date time values for other events.
- Makes use of the descriptions of the conflicts and filter them by comparing that to your room.